# Access VBA - Function to create an array with the names of all the worksheets of a selected excel workbook

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using Access trying to upload all the worksheets of an excel (which I select) as table to the Database.
To do so, I am creating a function that I recall in my procedure; this function should read the names of the worksheets in my excel file and save them in an array/collection (which one do you suggests? the number of worksheets is not fixed). This is my code for the moment but it doesn't work properly because I find in my array only the last worksheet and not all the previous ones:

```
Function Get_Sheetsname_Array(xlsfile)
    Dim sheetsLst As Collection
    Dim lookupWB As Excel.Application
    Dim txt As String
    
    Set lookupWB = New Excel.Application
    lookupWB.Workbooks.Open xlsfile
    
    toIndex = lookupWB.Worksheets.Count
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    With lookupWB
        For Each wrksheet In .Worksheets
            sheetsLst = Array(.xlSheet.Name)
        Next wrksheet
    End With


    Get_Sheetsname_Array = sheetLst
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently overwrites each sheet name, so only the last is saved in the variable. You need to add them to the array without overwriting. Something like this:

```
Sub SaveSheetsIntoArray()
    Dim shArray, i
    ReDim shArray(1 To Sheets.count)
    For i = 1 To Sheets.count
        shArray(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        Debug.Print shArray(i)
    Next
    'do something with the array "shArray"
End Sub
```

Also, add an "Option Explicit" as the first line in your VBA code, if not already there.

Comment: Did this help you? If not, tell us if you need more information to solve your problem. If yes, close it by accepting this as an answer.